# FromTensor + TensorContract gives unexpected result for a tensor product of vectors and a matrix

Tags: tensors

I have written a larger code that uses the `TensorSimplify` package written by Carl Woll for tensor manipulations. The code, however, produces unexpected results, which I have been able to narrow down to a few lines using `TensorProduct` and subsequently `TensorContract` and `FromTensor`. Here is a typical example in a standalone form (including installation of the package):

```
PacletInstall["TensorSimplify", 
  "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"];
<< TensorSimplify`
$Assumptions = {(u|v) \[Element] Vectors[d],A \[Element] Matrices[{d, d}]};
TensorContract[u\[TensorProduct]A\[TensorProduct]v, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] // FromTensor
TensorContract[A\[TensorProduct]u\[TensorProduct]v, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}}] // FromTensor
```

Both evaluation lines produce `v.Transpose[A].u` while I would in both cases expect `v.A.u`. Is there something trivial about the way that `TensorContract` or `FromTensor` works that I am misunderstanding?

Comment: This is a bug in FromTensor (I forgot that Dot[a] autoevaluates to a). I will push a fix tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in my code, fixed with version 0.0.3. Should work now. From a fresh kernel:

```
PacletUninstall["TensorSimplify"]
PacletInstall["TensorSimplify","Site"->"http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"];
<<TensorSimplify`
$Assumptions={(u|v) ∈ Vectors[d],A ∈ Matrices[{d,d}]};
TensorContract[u \[TensorProduct] A \[TensorProduct]v,{{1,3},{2,4}}]//FromTensor
TensorContract[A \[TensorProduct] u \[TensorProduct]v,{{1,4},{2,3}}]//FromTensor
```

> v.A.u
>
> v.A.u

Comment: Fantastic!!! Thank you so much for the quick fix of the bug!